# R process$new write stdout and stderr to same file

Tags: r, process, callr

In my R code I call another R script as a separate process like this

```
rp <- callr::process$new(command  = "rcode.R", args     = c("--date", date)
        , stdout   = 'logfile.txt', stderr   = 'logfile.txt'
        , cleanup  = FALSE
        , echo_cmd = TRUE
)
```

Both logger messages as well as any errors are getting written to same log file. But the error messages are writing on top of the file instead of writing on the bottom of the page

Sample logfile

```
Error in eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir) : 
  object 'filepath' not found
Calls: script2... glue_data ->  -> .transformer -> eval -> eval
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In rm(var traceback available 
lEnv") :
INFO [2021-04-20 13:30:37] date : 2021-03-28 
INFO [2021-04-20 13:30:37] user : aaa
INFO [2021-04-20 13:30:37] param2 : value
```

In the above sample log file when the error occured i would like the error to print at the end of the file

May I ask a sub question too? why `rp$get_exit_status()` returns `zero` even after there is an error in the code?

Comment: 1) You should load the packages you are using with `library(process)`; 2) What are the values of `cmd`, `date` and `logfile`? Like this the error is not reproducible.

Comment: Isn't this `library(processx)`?

Comment: @r2evans Yes, sorry for the typo :(.

Comment: FYI, this has been discussed before, https://github.com/r-lib/processx/issues/103 (since closed). I believe `processx::run` does not allow you to write both to a single file safely/simultaneously; the best offered was to write both to `"|"` and poll in R (not always the best answer).

Comment: btw, the reason that the error appears first is likely either due to blind luck (it might be last in other runs) or due to the stderr being flushed first, then the process exits, and then stdout is flushed.

Comment: Sorry the library was `callr` . updated the question